# Обход большого количества директорий на Python

Tags: python, файлы, ос

Есть такая проблема - нужно собрать определенные директории с определенными файлами среди огромного количества этих директорий и файлов. В конечный список попадают не все папки и файлы, но обход нужно совершить по всем, так как ищутся конкретные. Количество папок где то 40к, файлов более 30кк. Пробовал делать через `os.walk()` но такой поиск почему то с определенного момента захлебывается. Все эти манипуляции делаются на сервере с хорошей начинкой. Есть ли какие то решения для такой задачи?

Comment: Какая операционка? Сколько папоп/файлов может быть в одном каталоге? Тот же Windows очень не любит, когда в одном каталоге больше 20к каталогов/файлов и начинает дико тупить на уровне системы при обращении к таким каталогам.

Comment: Что значит "захлебывается"? В любом случае, судя по количеству файлов, даже если вы просто проверяете названия файлов, то поиск должен занимать около 30-300 секунд в зависимости от многих условий

Comment: Ну и как определяются определенные категории с определенными файлами?

Comment: ОС - винда 7. Захлебывается - это я проверял флагами по 500 каталогов, и где то на 10к каталогах процесс, постепенно затормаживаясь, останавливается совсем. При этом процесс питона не занимает много памяти, мегабайт 10, и проц не нагружает совсем.